# Why change in Observable variable triggers change in View Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm learning Angular, so I'm building todo app. Todos are fetched from API, and every one of them has a project as parent. In a view I'm adding new project which triggers addNewProject method in service which in turn triggers POST request to the API in another service. Projects are listed in the sidebar, bind to input from parent component. ProjectsService holds array of projects in a private field, and has observable which is used by main component.

I'm struggling to understand why on earth appending private property _projects after API call in the service triggers change in MainComponent property even though _projects is private and change in Observable from array should not trigger functions passed from Observers.

Parent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  projects: Project[] = new Array<Project>();

  constructor(private projectsService: ProjectsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectsService.projects$.subscribe((projects) => {
      this.projects = projects;
    });
  }

  addNewProject(newProjectName: string) {
    this.projectsService.addNewProject(newProjectName);
  }

}
```

Sidebar:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() projects: Project[];
  @Output() projectEntered = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  projectAdded(projectName: string) {
    this.projectEntered.emit(projectName);
  }

}
```

Service:

```
export class ProjectsService {

  private _projects$: Observable<Array<Project>> = new Observable<Array<Project>>();
  private _projects: Project[] = [];
  private _loadedProject$: Observable<Project>;
  private _projectsLoaded: boolean;
  private _taskForProject: object;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private api: ApiService) {
  }

  loadAllProjects() {

    this._projects$ = this.api.getAllProjectsByUserId(this.userService.userId).pipe(
      map((projects) => {
        this._projects = projects;
        return this._projects;
      })
    );
  }

  get projects$() {
    if (!this._projectsLoaded) {
      this.loadAllProjects();
    }
    return this._projects$;
  }

  getAllTasks() {
    return this.api.getAllTasksByUserId(this.userService.userId);
  }

  getProject(projectId: string) {
    this._loadedProject$ = this.api.getProjectById(projectId);
    return this._loadedProject$;
  }

  getTodayTasksForProject(tasks: Task[]) {
    const todayTasks: Task[] = [];
    const todayDate = new Date();
    tasks.forEach((task) => {
      if (new Date(task.completionPlannedDate).getDate() === todayDate.getDate()) {
        tasks.splice(tasks.indexOf(task), 1);
        todayTasks.push(task);
      }
    });
    return todayTasks;
  }

  getTomorrowTasksForProject(tasks: Task[]) {
    const tomorrowTasks: Task[] = [];
    const tomorrowDate = new Date(new Date().getDate() + 1);
    tasks.forEach((task) => {
      if (new Date(task.completionPlannedDate).getDate() === tomorrowDate.getDate()) {
        tasks.splice(tasks.indexOf(task), 1);
        tomorrowTasks.push(task);
      }
    });
    return tomorrowTasks;
  }

  getUpcomingTasks(tasks: Task[]) {
    const upcomingTasks: Task[] = [];
    const upcomingDate = new Date(new Date().getDate() + 2);
    tasks.forEach((task) => {
      if (new Date(task.completionPlannedDate).getDate() > upcomingDate.getDate()) {
        tasks.splice(tasks.indexOf(task), 1);
        upcomingTasks.push(task);
      }
    });
    return upcomingTasks;
  }

  addNewProject(projectName: string) {
    this.api.postNewProject({
      id: null,
      userId: this.userService.userId,
      title: projectName,
      tasks: []
    }).subscribe((project: Project) => {
      this._projects.push(project);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#what-causes-change):

> Basically application state change can be caused by three things:
>
> - Events - click, submit
> - XHR - Fetching data from a remote server
> - Timers - setTimeout(), setInterval()

If you don't want change detection to fire try changing to [ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4)